# How do I run my Ionic app (with Meteor backend) on IOS device?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, meteor, build

I'm trying to run my Ionic app on an IOS device but it does not work correctly. I'm using Meteor as my backend/api. When I build my app, it does actually start up the app and brings me to the login screen, but I can't login..

This is the error message I get after trying to login:

```
ERROR: {"_body":{"isTrusted":true},"status":0,"ok":false,"statusText":"","headers":{},"type":3,"url":null}
```

I build my IOS app like this:

- cordova platform add ios
- cordova build ios
- cordova emulate ios

Running the app on my device by booting from Xcode does not work either.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: is the app running in the browser?

Comment: Yes, the app is running in the browser, but not on my device or in my simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While building IOS app from IONIC, you need to allow the cross origin platform header because IOS in default uses web view which needs the [CORS allowed](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/http-post-request-error-no-access-control-origin-in-ionic/106029). You can either append **('access-control-allow-origin', '*')** in the headers for every http request.

Or

You have to allow the CORS in the backend

Comment: I already have that line within my code: 


`Meteor.startup(() => {
  //
  // Enable cross origin requests for all endpoints
  JsonRoutes.setResponseHeaders({
    'Cache-Control': 'no-store',
    Pragma: 'no-cache',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With',
  });
});`


It is still not working tho